# Восстановление текста из отрывка в виде фонетической транскрипции

Tags: фонетика

От текста сохранился лишь отрывок в виде следующей фонетической записи [надатап'ит']. Нужно восстановить текст разными способами.

Answer (score 2):

Можно еще: "Надо-то пить!" или "На дотопить" ("На дрова дотопить печку").

Comment: Согласен. Видел эти варианты. Но уж больно экзотично.

Answer (score 1):

"Надо топить". 
"Но дотопить" - не подходит, О не редуцируется -  [нодадап'ит']

А что такое "разные способы"? Разные варианты восстановления текста - или разные приемы? Я что-то не очень знаю о последних.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Буквально написано так : восстановить текст записки, от которой сохранился только отрывок- фонетическая запись. Предложите разные варианты.

Answer (score 0):

В нормальной записи - "Надо топить", "но дотопить".